# Localizar um grupo numérico na string

Tags: sql-server, string

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda para localizar um grupo de 20 números dentro de uma string que possui caracteres e símbolos.
Digamos que minha string tem 165 caracteres, quero os números de 127 a 147 que são meu grupo "*00001138271467122784*", mas o tamanho da string nas outras linhas é variado, meu numero pode começar antes ou depois, a ordem de inicio e fim não é fixa.
Eu tenho '_' para poder delimitar, mas como?
SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Este exemplo, "00001138271467122784", não tem nem 127 nem 147 como sequências. Poderia colocar mais exemplos?

Comment: Não é isso Cigano, o tamanho da string é de 165 caracteres, o meu exemplo esta na posição inicial 127 e posição final 147, mas apenas neste exemplo, em outra linha a posição (localização) muda.
quero pegar todo o conjunto 00001138271467122784 que sempre é de 20 caracteres.

Esta é a string
file%3A%2F%2F%2Fmnt%2FABOX%2FRESULTS%2Fresults%2Fresults%2Ftxt%2F20160628105952000_083021988480019_38505_4524425_170_2239408_>>>00001138271467122784<<<<_41_53_ATENDENTE.txt

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado por esclarecer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eis demonstração do uso da função [charindex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186323.aspx) para encontrar o trecho que procura.

```
 -- código #1
declare @URL varchar(2000);
set @URL= 'file%3A%2F%2F%2Fmnt%2FABOX%2FRESULTS%2Fresults%2Fresults%2Ft‌​xt%2F201606281059520‌​00_083021988480019_3‌​8505_4524425_170_223‌​9408_>>>000011382714‌​67122784<<<<_41_53_A‌​TENDENTE.txt';

PRINT charindex('00001138271467122784', @URL);
```

O código para pesquisar nas linhas de uma tabela pode ser algo como:

```
-- código #2
declare @Txt char(20);
set @Txt= '00001138271467122784';

SELECT URL, 
       [Posição]= charindex(@Txt, URL)
  from tabela;
```

---

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

> *Acabei de descobrir um padrão os conjuntos que quero, estão entre o sexto '_' e o antepenúltimo '_' (9 da contagem) sempre assim, então preciso de algo que pegue a posição deles, do sexto e do Nono '_' e entre eles esta o campo que quero.*

Considerando-se as explicações adicionais sobre o separador "_", pode-se criar uma função específica para obter o conteúdo entre os sexto e nono "_".

```
-- código #4 v3
CREATE FUNCTION analisaURL (@pURL varchar(2000))
       returns @pToken varchar(200) as
begin
declare @I int, @Pos6 int, @Pos9 int;

-- obtém sexto "_"
set @Pos6= 0;
set @I= 0;
while @I <> 6
  begin
  set @Pos6= charindex('_', @pURL, (@Pos6 +1));
  set @I += 1;
  end;

-- obtém nono "_"
set @Pos9= @Pos6;
while @I <> 9
  begin
  set @Pos9= charindex('_', @pURL, (@Pos9 +1));
  set @I += 1;
  end;

return substring(@pURL, (@Pos6 +1), (@Pos9 - @Pos6 -1));
end;
go
```

Avalie com atenção o código da função, pois não foi testada. Recomenda-se acrescentar tratamento de erro na função.

A utilização da função fica desta forma:

```
-- código #5
SELECT T.URL, dbo.analisaURL(T.URL) as Token
  from tabela as T;
```

---

Outra opção é utilizar função do tipo *split string* para dividir a URL em partes e a seguir selecionar somente a sétima parte de cada URL.

```
-- código #3 v2
with cteSplitURL as (
SELECT T.URL, S.ItemNumber as seq, S.Item as token
  from tabela as T
       outer apply dbo.SplitURL(T.URL, '_') as S
)
SELECT URL, token
  from cteSplitURL
  where seq = 7;
```

O código #3 é o esboço do código; você deve acrescentar função do tipo *split string* que retorne tokens e a sequência dele no *string*.

Artigos contendo funções *split string*:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: Olá @José Diz, obrigado pela ajuda mas nesse caso que sitou, eu sempre vou acabar encontrando o mesmo numero '00001138271467122784' eu gostaria de procurar na string o mesmo conjunto, digo pegar sempre uma cadeia de 20 números agrupados.
nao importa se tem (posicao 0)00123456....(posicao 20) quero sempre localizar um determinado grupo entende?
esses numeros são os unicos a terem 20 caraceteres numericos em sequencia.

Comment: Acabei de descobrir um padrão os conjuntos que quero, estão entre o sexto '_' e o antepenúltimo '_' (9 da contagem) sempre assim, então preciso de algo que pegue a posição deles, do sexto e do Nono '_' e entre eles esta o campo que quero.

Comment: @KalebGabriel: Quando possível, avalie o código #5.

Comment: irei estudar o código que me passou, isto que estou fazendo é um select para mirar as informações do banco para o qlikview.
Vou analisar direitinho, mas me disseram que eu poderia fazer com charindex pegar a posição e depois usar substring, mas eu nao consigo fazer o calculo no substring.

Comment: Tenho as linhas F:
CHARINDEX('_', uri, CHARINDEX('_', uri,CHARINDEX('_', uri,CHARINDEX('_', uri, CHARINDEX('_', uri, CHARINDEX('_', uri, 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) AS f

E linha G:
CHARINDEX('_', uri, CHARINDEX('_', uri,CHARINDEX('_', uri,CHARINDEX('_', uri, CHARINDEX('_', uri, CHARINDEX('_', uri, CHARINDEX('_', uri, 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) AS g

não consigo fazer o calculo com os apelidos deles f e g
SUBSTRING(uri, f + 1, g - f - 1))) AS ucid

Comment: @KalebGabriel: Vejo como uma complicação essa sequência de charindex. Conhece o princípio KISS?  Se ainda não, acesse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle //

Comment: Uma pergunta, é possível usar o apelido de uma coluna dentro  de uma função?
por exemplo usei o charindex pra pegar as posições, meu charindex de apelido F e G são respectivamente as posições iniciais e finais, consigo usar no substring? Substring(uri, F, G)? nao deu certo nao reconhece

Comment: @KalebGabriel: O macete, nesse caso, é utilizar CTE: with cteX as (*código da consulta*) SELECT substring(URI, F, (G - F -1)) from cteX; // Ou subconsulta:  SELECT substring(URI, F, (G - F -1)) from (*código da consulta*) as T; // Acho que é isso.

Comment: Isso mesmo obrigado. \o/